# Auth0 with auth0-lock only authenticates when using debugger, to slowly step through code

Tags: authentication, angular, asp.net-core, auth0

So as the title says, I'm trying to use `auth0-lock` with Angular 2 SPA and an ASP.NET Core API. I'm having trouble authenticating myself for testing. I am also using `webpack` to pack the app and have deleted all other references down to just the bare auth app.

I followed their tutorial here: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2

The problem is when I hit the constructor it will only authenticate if I slowly step through the library code with debugger.

```
constructor() {
      debugger
    // Add callback for lock `authenticated` event
      this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult) => {
        debugger
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
    });
  }
```

If I remove the debuggers and let it run at the normal speed it will never authenticate; the `auth0-lock` will come up and I can login then it'll reload, but I won't be logged in nor will there be anything in the local storage.

**UPDATE:**  So I think I found the cause for this issue. Using Angular 2's most recent component router; If I comment the routing out, the auth works instantly, but putting it back in I have to use the debugger to slow it down. Otherwise, it won't `auth`. Is there any way to fix this?

I am also having another problem when I am authenticated, querying my API I get a response `401 Unauthorized` even though `Auth0` is saying I am authorized. I can see my token in `localStorage` as well as the use of `authHttp` module found in `angular2-jwt` coming from another one of `Auth0` tutorials on angular 2.

My backend (asp.net Core) has as a method with `[Authorise]`. I followed the setup from here https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/aspnet-core-webapi  on how to get going, except I'm having the issues above.

**UPDATE:** So it turns out this issue was casued by me skipping over the part in the tutorial on changing the `SignatureAlgorithm` to use `RS256` I've changed it to use the RS256 method and is working fine on that side of things now still having the issue where it wont auth when I have routing enabled on angular 2 though
Here's the Github Repo for the project: https://github.com/Toxicable/Templates

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the problem around authentication when routing is enabled, this may be related to the fact that the Angular 2 [router will not preserve query and fragment parameters upon navigation](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/23ee29b6a2ae396f6ec13f71c9552e3e0a983c3c).

This would mean that Auth0 Lock would not see the authentication related parameters in the URL and as such would not authenticate the user. If this is the case, try following the procedures indicated in this other answer ([How to use the HashLocationStrategy with the Auth0 Lock widget for user login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641554/how-to-use-the-hashlocationstrategy-with-the-auth0-lock-widget-for-user-login/39701248#39701248)), although that ones solves it for the case of routing using the `HashLocationStrategy` which I don't know if it's your case.