# Angular2 Auth0 Token Not Being Stored When Using Options In Auth0Lock Object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, auth0

I am using Auth0 to authenticate users in my NG2 app. I setup `AuthGuard` to block users from accessing certain pages in the application without a token.

When I use the Lock widget without any options the token is saved to the `localStorage` with no problems. However, if I use the options it is not saved to the `localStorage`.

To be more specific I can use some options, but when I add `auth:` and its parameters the token will not save to the `localStorage`.

This is the part that causes the problem:

```
auth: { responseType: 'token', redirect: true, redirectUrl: "http://localhost/dashboard" },
```

When it is added to the options it will not save the token to the `localStorage`.

File `auth.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable }                      from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired, JwtHelper }      from 'angular2-jwt';
import { Router }                          from '@angular/router';
import { myConfig }                        from './auth.config';

declare var Auth0Lock: any;

var options = {
  theme: { logo: '../assets/img/logo.png', primaryColor: '#779476' },
  auth: { responseType: 'token', redirect: true, redirectUrl: "http://localhost/dashboard" },
  languageDictionary: { emailInputPlaceholder: "eve@example.com", title: "Login" }, 
};

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
  lock = new Auth0Lock(myConfig.clientID, myConfig.domain, options, {});

  constructor( private router: Router ) {
    this.lock.on('authenticated', (authResult) => {
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
    });
  }

  public login() { this.lock.show(); };
  public logout() { localStorage.removeItem('id_token'); };
  public authenticated() { return tokenNotExpired(); };
}
```

File `guard.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable }           from '@angular/core';
import {
    CanActivate,
    Router,
    ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    RouterStateSnapshot
}                               from '@angular/router';
import { Auth }                 from './auth.service';
import { Observable }           from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class Guard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(protected router: Router, protected auth: Auth ) {}

     canActivate() {
        if (localStorage.getItem('id_token')) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        }
        // not logged in so redirect to login page
        this.router.navigate(['/pages/home']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you do not pass explicit `auth` options the default value for `redirect` is `true` and for `responseType` is `token` so it seems that the culprit is `redirectUrl`. Confirm if this is not something similar the issue mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39701248/204699); it does seem to be, because if Angular clears the route parameters the Lock event won't get fired to save the token.

Comment: @JoãoAngelo thanks for getting back to me. This has been quite the confusing issue and I can not find any information regarding the functionality of using auth in options. How this changes the default behavior. But I did find that by removing of token is returned on default. But with auth and token not set to true it is not. So I removed auth and added  this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard'); to the constructor and once the user is authenticated it redirects the user to the correct location. I assume this behavior of auth just needs to be documented better.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this at your this.lock settings.

```
auth: {
    redirect:false,
  }
```

Source:

- auth0.com/forum/t/authenticated-event-not-triggering/3554
- github.com/auth0/lock/issues/527

If you still want to stick to redirect feature, you can try to get those things on your own. See here for details: auth0.com/forum/t/callback-url-begins-with-hash/3694