# Angular 2 with Auth0 routing error 404

Tags: angular, authentication, typescript, auth0

I'm using Auth0 authentication in my Angular 2 application.

Everything OK in my application running localhost, but when I run it on Server (on my domain) I got stuck.

My problems seems to be in the routes, but everything I know is: I guess.

**Problem:**

I can do the login using the Auth0 in my Angular app (no problem, both localhost and on server - also the logout). After the login, the application redirects to my Control Page, no problem too, and inside the application I have the menu, my other pages with their routes, etc.

In localhost OK, BUT on Server after the login I can't navigate betwen the pages in my app. Everything goes wrong and I just got a 404 page (even when I just refresh).

I'm also using JQuery and Materialize CSS. The JQuery doesn't load, after I refresh it's load and the effects work.

**Code:**

*app.routing.ts*:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth.guard';

import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { PainelComponent } from './components/painel/painel.component';
import { ReunioesComponent } from './components/reunioes/reunioes.component';
import { AssociadosComponent } from './components/associados/associados.component';
import { CalendarioComponent } from './components/calendario/calendario.component';
import { TesourariaComponent } from './components/tesouraria/tesouraria.component';
import { DocumentosComponent } from './components/documentos/documentos.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'painel',
        component: PainelComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'associados',
        component: AssociadosComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'calendario',
        component: CalendarioComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'reunioes',
        component: ReunioesComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'tesouraria',
        component: TesourariaComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'documentos',
        component: DocumentosComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: false})
```

*auth.service.ts*:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';

declare var Auth0Lock: any;

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
    lock = new Auth0Lock('SECRET', 'SECRET.auth0.com', {});

    constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult) => {
            this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, (err, profile) => {
                if(err)
                    throw new Error(err)

                localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
                localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);

                this.router.navigate(['/painel'])
            })
        });
    }

    public login() {
        this.lock.show()
    }

    public authenticated() {
        return tokenNotExpired()
    }

    public logout() {
        localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
        localStorage.removeItem('profile')
    }
}
```

*sidenav.partial.html*:

```
<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed">
    <li><a href="/associados"><i class="material-icons">group</i>Associados</a></li>
    <li><a href="/calendario"><i class="material-icons">event</i>Calendário</a></li>
    <li><a href="/painel"><i class="material-icons">new_releases</i>Calendário Próximo</a></li>
    <li><a href="/reunioes"><i class="material-icons">forum</i>Reuniões</a></li>
    <li><a href="/tesouraria"><i class="material-icons">monetization_on</i>Tesouraria</a></li>
    <li><a href="/documentos"><i class="material-icons">attach_file</i>Documentos</a></li>
    <li><br></li>
    <li class="show-on-med-and-down hide-on-large-only">
         <a href="#!" (click)="auth.logout()"><i class="material-icons">close</i>Sair</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Ow I think I just understood your question... what web server are you running ?

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a third-party site.

Comment: Mike McCaughan I added it, thanks for the warning. I expect that help more people with the same problem in the code. The problem was solved Jack Clancy.

Comment: @PauloTokarskiGlinski glad to help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I ran into a similar issue to you when implementing Auth0 in my ng2 app. It has to do with the way you implemented routing. You will need to use `HashLocationStrategy.` This requires adding this to your providers array in `app.module.ts`:

`{
   provide: LocationStrategy,
   useClass: HashLocationStrategy
 },`

Once you have added this, you can follow the guide below to correctly implement hash routing with auth0 (use workaround #2 if you're using a more recent version of ng2):

[How to use the HashLocationStrategy with the Auth0 Lock widget for user login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641554/how-to-use-the-hashlocationstrategy-with-the-auth0-lock-widget-for-user-login)