# Routing with Angular return 404

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I've this problem with Routing Component on the Host server when copy the ng build files.
But on the localhost:4200 ( local development )  all routes work perfectly.

So for example this route that does not contain any AuthGuard.

**localhost**

localhost:4200/vendo   - I can see the component

**on server**

exapme.mysite.com/vendo  - Only see the error 404

**app.routing.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/index';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/index';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/index';
import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/index';
import { EstadoComponent} from  './_estadoactual/estado.component'
import {PublicarComponent} from "./_admin_apk/publicar.component";
import {PidoComponent} from "./pido/pido.component";
import {DepoComponent} from "./depo/depo.component";
import {DepoChessComponent} from "./depochess/depochess.component";
import {ProductosComponent} from "./productos/productos.component";
import {SamComponent} from "./sam/sam.component";
import {VendoComponent} from "./vendo/vendo.component";
import {SamdplusComponent} from "./samdplus/samdplus.component";
import {GcmComponent} from "./gcm/gcm.component";
import {GcmNotificationComponent} from "./gcm/gcm-notification.component";

const appRoutes: Routes = [

    { path: 'ada2/login', component: LoginComponent  },
    { path: 'ada2/depo', component: DepoComponent },
    { path: 'ada2/pido', component: PidoComponent },
    { path: 'ada2/vendo', component: VendoComponent},
    { path: 'ada2/sam', component: SamComponent },
    { path: 'ada2/samdplus', component: SamdplusComponent},
    { path: 'ada2/depochess', component: DepoChessComponent },
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]  },
    { path: 'ada2', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    { path: 'ada2/home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'ada2/publicar', component: PublicarComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'ada2/register', component: RegisterComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'ada2/estado', component: EstadoComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'ada2/productos', component: ProductosComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'ada2/gcm', component: GcmComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'ada2/gcmnotification', component: GcmNotificationComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 with Auth0 routing error 404](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234947/angular-2-with-auth0-routing-error-404)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have flagged this question as a duplicate but will answer it here anyway because there are some slight differences in context. A way to fix this issue is using `HashLocationStrategy`. You can include these lines in the provider array of your app.module.ts file:

`{
   provide: LocationStrategy,
   useClass: HashLocationStrategy
 },`

Once you have added this, you can follow the guide below to correctly implement hash routing. If you are using jsonwebtokens or Auth0 to perform authentication, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641554/how-to-use-the-hashlocationstrategy-with-the-auth0-lock-widget-for-user-login) should help point you in the right direction.

Comment: thats ok, but the URL now have this # on the url path thats correct?
http://trainer.amalgamesoft.com/#/myworkouts/exe

Comment: That is correct. You can use that routing principle, or as i said in my answer, use HTML 5 routing, and configuratate you server with in .htaccess

Comment: Yes that is how the URL should look now. @mario's answer is also valid

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are not using HashLocationStrategy. Which means that you need to setup your server to handle routing towards index.html file.

This got my project working on wamp server. Edit .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
```