# Hybrid Mobile App with Angular and Android Studio

Tags: android, angular, android-studio

I am in a Crisis. I am new to Angular & even newer to Android Studio and having shot all my resources in trying to figure this out, sorry if this is an obvious thing....

**Question:** Why is it when I try to launch my Angular App through Android Studio, that I am getting a 404 error.

**Explanation:** The goal was to launch my angular web app to the playstore by making it an hybrid app by wrapping it in a webview through android studio... I am following this web tutorial for this task... 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5dlmqM9Oo8 
This works if I test a website address like google, but if i try my angular app address, the screen remains blank or returns a 404 "the requested URL was not found on this server". I have launched my Angular App on a personal server and it works perfectly through my browser. 
my guess is something with the routing in angular is preventing the webview from loading the app... I have tried the following fixes with no changes...

1) Hash
[How to use the HashLocationStrategy with the Auth0 Lock widget for user login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641554/how-to-use-the-hashlocationstrategy-with-the-auth0-lock-widget-for-user-login)

```
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash: true})], ...
```

2) .htaccess in the apache server 
https://angular.io/guide/deployment#development-servers

```
    RewriteEngine On
       # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
       RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
       RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
       RewriteRule ^ - [L]
       # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
    RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

If you need more code please let me know. I'm not sure if this is possible, but if not I am going to have to learn Ionic or figure something else out. Thanks stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I really hope this helps someone who is in need. I think part of the issue is this Angular Mobile App uses localstorage for JWT and has some API's for the database...
 
Anyhow, the fix came from Android Studio

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       private WebView myWebView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web1);
            WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       // THE FIX WAS THESE TWO LINES BELOW //
            myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

            myWebView.loadUrl("MYANGULARAPPWEBSITE");
            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        }
    }
```